# How to subset a dataset ito remove rows with certain values in any column?

Tags: r

So I have a dataframe like the below and I want to remove all rows with columns a, b or c containing values equal to one of a few numbers.

i.e. in the below if I wanted to remove the rows with entries equal to 1, I would want only the second row (I want to ignore the first few columns).

| nothing | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | 1 |

Returns :

| nothing | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 |

Should note there are many columns after the first few that I want to ignore, so I don't want to name them individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::if_any`.

```r
df %>% 
  filter(!if_any(c(a,b,c), ~ .x == 1))
  nothing a b c
1       1 2 3 2
```

You can also select with `-` or `:` if the columns are consecutive:

```r
filter(df, !if_any(-nothing, ~ .x == 1))
filter(df, !if_any(a:c, ~ .x == 1))
```

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(nothing = c(1L, 1L, 1L), a = c(1L, 2L, 4L), b = c(2L, 
3L, 6L), c = c(8L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I want to exclude numbers other than 1? Can I just use ==c(1, 2, ... ) etc. ?

Comment: In that case, you must use %in%, not ==, so it'd be e.g. `filter(df, !if_any(-nothing, ~ .x %in% c(1,2)))`

Comment: Or may use `if_all` `df %>% filter(if_all(-nothing, ~ .x != 1))`

Answer (score 1):

A solution using base-r.

```
## identify which rows in the df contain 1s
rows_to_remove = which(df[,-1] == 1, arr.ind=T)[,1]
# subset these rows
df[-rows_to_remove,]
```

```
  nothing a b c
2       1 2 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case we could use `filter` with `across` and an anonymous function without `if_any`.

```
library(dplyr)

filter(df, across(a:c, ~. != 1))
```

```
  nothing a b c
1       1 2 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df[rowSums(df[-1]==1)==0,]
```